# Remove tag on StackOverflow

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag `x-window-system` is automatically remapped to `x11`  - I have just retagged all questions to the `x11` tag.

Please can someone remove the `x-window-system` tag?

Is this the correct way to remove these tags as I plan to go through more tags on SO as a clean up exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synonym is in place and all the questions are retagged.

There is nothing more to do here.

Any new questions tagged x-window-system will be tagged x11 automatically.